# WPF MouseEnter does not fire when MouseButton is Pressed

Tags: drag-and-drop, mouseenter, mousedown

**In short:** If any mouse button is Pressed when the mouse enters a WPF window, all mouse events are ignored *regardless* of whether the mouse is captured by any process.

**The Challenge**

Create two WPF 4.5 projects. In the first one, add a Border with a MouseDown handler. Inside that handler, do everything you can think of to release mouse capture:

```
        this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        element.ReleaseMouseCapture(); // "sender" 

        Mouse.Capture(null);

        while (Mouse.Captured != null)
            Mouse.Captured.ReleaseMouseCapture(); 

        ReleaseCapture(); //Win32.ReleaseCapture()
```

In the other project, add a MouseEnter handler to the default grid that will change its Background.

Start them both up, MouseDown on the border and "drag" to the other window. Until you release the mouse button, the second Window's background will not change.

What's really annoying is that if you stay within the first window, the attempts to "uncapture" the mouse appear to work. Add another element in the first window with a MouseEnter handler, and it will fire just fine. This implies that WPF doesn't know or care about cross-process capture. It just ignores events if any mouse button is in the Pressed state when the mouse first enters an application.

Anyone know if it's possible to have WPF elements respond to mouse events when the mouse was pressed before entering them?

Comment: Basic Windows behavior, unrelated to WPF.  Only the active window in the foreground gets keyboard and mouse up/down notifications.

Comment: Wow, good point. That seems incredibly obvious now that I think about it. I got so hung up on mouse capture that I didn't consider that aspect of the problem. Thanks :)